# What is the right ComponentName to use with ProviderUpdateRequester() so Android Wear 2.0 will update my complication data?

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

To tell the Android Wear Watch Face my complication data has been updated, I need to use the ProviderUpdateRequester() method, but it needs a ComponentName. Which is the right component name to use?

**Details:**

I am building a data provider for the Complications feature in Android Wear 2.0 (complications go in Watch Faces).

You can provide an update period to the system via the manifest, but I want to only update the data when there is new data.

It states in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/complications.html#update_period), *"You can alternatively use a "push style" to send updates, rather than requesting updates on a fixed schedule. To do so, you can set the update period to 0 so scheduled update requests do not occur (or set it to a non-zero value) and use a ProviderUpdateRequester to trigger calls to onComplicationUpdate as required.".*

However, it does not give a snippet of the correct ComponentName to use. I have tried this with no luck:

```
ComponentName.createRelative(MyService.this,MyService.class.getSimpleName());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
ComponentName componentName =
  new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
```

I actually wrote a sample that demonstrates how to do this on GitHub [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace).

The class the does the work is [UpdateComplicationDataService.java class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/provider/UpdateComplicationDataService.java).

Here is the full code excerpt if interested:

```
ComponentName componentName =
  new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

ProviderUpdateRequester providerUpdateRequester = 
  new ProviderUpdateRequester(getApplicationContext(), componentName);

// This method only updates the specific complication id, you could
// update all with providerUpdateRequester.requestUpdateAll().
providerUpdateRequester.requestUpdate(complicationId);
```